# How to get next row value based on previous row excluding week ends in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, lead

I have a table as follows: (Expected result without weekend exclude logic)

| Start Date | End Date(Expected Date) | No of Days(input) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 2 |
| 03-01-2021 | 08-01-2021 | 5 |
| 09-01-2021 | 10-01-2021 | 2 |
| 11-01-2021 | 20-01-2021 | 10 |
| 21-01-2021 | 09-02-2021 | 20 |
| 10-02-2021 | 10-02-2021 | 1 |

I want to re-generate the `StartDate` and `EndDate` data based on the `NumberOfDays` values, and the `StartDate` for subsequent rows based on previous row's `EndDate + 1 day` and in this sequence, I need to **exclude the weekend dates** as well, and I have another scenario to include weekend dates based on condition.

I want to apply this logic and select the data in same select query using SQL Server.

This is what I have tried

```sql
declare @t table ( StartDate date, EndDate date, DaysToAdd int );

insert into @t(StartDate, EndDate, DaysToAdd)
 values('20210217', '20210227', 10), ('20210312', '20210310', 10), ('20210326', '20210401', 10), ('20210409', '20210401', 10), ('20210507', '20210401', 10), ('20210606', '20210529', 10), ('20210618', '20210417', 3), ('20210620', '20210309', 2), ('20300913', '20210227', 2), (null, '20300914', 4);

select * from @t

select dateadd(day, -DaysToAdd-1+count(*) over(order by isnull(StartDate, EndDate), EndDate) + sum(DaysToAdd) over(order by isnull(StartDate, EndDate), EndDate), min(StartDate) over()) as NewStartDate, dateadd(day, -1+count(*) over(order by isnull(StartDate, EndDate), EndDate) + sum(DaysToAdd) over(order by isnull(StartDate, EndDate), EndDate), min(StartDate) over()) as NewEndDate, * from @t;
```

My Expected result:

| Start Date | End Date(Expected Date) | No of Days(input) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 04-01-2021 | 2 |
| 05-01-2021 | 11-01-2021 | 5 |
| 12-01-2021 | 13-01-2021 | 2 |
| 14-01-2021 | 27-01-2021 | 10 |
| 28-01-2021 | 24-02-2021 | 20 |
| 25-02-2021 | 25-02-2021 | 1 |

Comment: please share with us your attempt

Comment: Is there another column that we can Order By? Like a primary key? You're asking to change values of both `StartDate` and `EndDate`. How will you then determine the order in which to process the rows?

Comment: I have another column in Sort order based on this column do the order by.

Comment: Showing us your expected results will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu, Above table format result will need to me

Comment: why there is a row with StartDate = NULL `(null, '20300914', 4)`

Comment: @Squirrel, Even the value is Null or not null `startDate` should generate from previous row's `EndDate+1`. We have scenarios where there can be null values in startDate/endDate in the middle, but the data should be generated based on first row's `startDate`.

Answer (score 0):

it is best if you have a calendar table

for the solution, i create a simple `calendar` table

```
create table calendar
(
    CalDate      date,
    isWeekEnd    bit
);
```

then populate it with dates

```
with rcte as
(
    select CalDate = convert(date, '2021-01-01')
    union all
    select CalDate = dateadd(day, 1, CalDate)
    from   rcte
    where  CalDate <= '2021-12-30'
)
insert into calendar (CalDate, isWeekEnd)
select CalDate, 
       case when left(datename(weekday, CalDate), 3) in ('Sat', 'Sun') then 1 else 0 end
from   rcte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

your sample table & data

```
declare @t table (id int identity, StartDate date, EndDate date, DaysToAdd int );

insert into @t(StartDate, EndDate, DaysToAdd)
values('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', 2), 
      ('2021-01-03', '2021-01-08', 5), 
      ('2021-01-09', '2021-01-10', 2), 
      ('2021-01-11', '2021-01-20', 10), 
      ('2021-01-21', '2021-02-09', 20), 
      ('2021-02-10', '2021-02-10', 1);
```

Since you only interested in the `StartDate` of first row, I select it into a variable

The actual query

```
declare @StartDate date;

select @StartDate = StartDate
from   @t
where  id = 1;

with 
cal as
(
    select CalDate, rn = row_number() over (order by CalDate)
    from   Calendar
    where  CalDate  >= @StartDate
    and    isWeekEnd = 0
),
t as
(
    select t.id, t.DaysToAdd,
           s = sum(t.DaysToAdd) over (order by t.id) - t.DaysToAdd + 1,
           e = sum(t.DaysToAdd) over (order by t.id)
    from   @t t
)
select t.id, 
       t.DaysToAdd,
       StartDate = s.CalDate,
       EndDate   = e.CalDate
from   t
       inner join cal s on t.s = s.rn
       inner join cal e on t.e = e.rn
order by t.id
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36179040c9309dd2a864cfa1332e9f80)

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, It gives the expected result, But in our case we need to achieve this without `calendar` table, here the start will be dynamic and in some cases we may have contract for 2 years. 

So We have to check whether Weekend while calculating `StartDate/EndDate`. Is there any direct solution for this?


Thanks in advance...!

Comment: If you are dealing with dates and weekends, you should seriously consider having a calendar table. It make things much easier. If for whatever reason you really can't have a calendar table, you can generate it on the fly in CTE based on the `min (date)` and `max(date)`